# I want to save a image from remote URL to local system in PHP

Tags: php, curl

this is my PHP code

```
<?php
$return = array();
$img_url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRriYVsmTPMn-8zkAKAtTzghAwUeQwaqmZCJTc127h7-WFYIpNS";
$imageUrl = $img_url;
$dd = pathinfo($imageUrl);
$pic_name=  $dd['basename'];

@$rawImage = file_get_contents($imageUrl);

if($rawImage)
{
    file_put_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/get_img/".$pic_name,$rawImage);

    echo 'Image Saved';
}
else
{

echo 'Error Occured';
}

?>
```

but for this URL from google images, this code is giving me this.
**"Warning: file_put_contents(C:/xampp/htdocs/get_img/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRriYVsmTPMn-8zkAKAtTzghAwUeQwaqmZCJTc127h7-WFYIpNS): failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_img\get1.php on line 12"**

how can i save this image?

Comment: You can't include neither "?" nor ":" in the filename

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will help you

```
$imageLink = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRriYVsmTPMn-8zkAKAtTzghAwUeQwaqmZCJTc127h7-WFYIpNS";
$random = mt_rand();
$size = getimagesize($imageLink);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);
$filename = $random . $extension;
$path = "/images/";
file_put_contents(getcwd() . $path . $filename, file_get_contents($imageLink));
```

Comment: Why jpg?. It might be .png

Comment: well like @Amarnasan ask, if there is any other extension instead "JPG" for image then what will we do?

Comment: @ghayourabbas For extension, how you will decide what type of image is??

Comment: Actually that's another problem: You should know what is the type of image and add the correct extension... otherwise, just store the file without the extension as your original code intended to do

Comment: How can one store file without extension?? You must defined the type of file and will be used at the time of fetching...

Comment: You can store file without extension. Just... do it. What is the problem?

Comment: @yash in my original code '$dd' returns me this array with extension as well.

Comment: Array
(
    [dirname] => http://www.themebin.com/wp-content/uploads/hd-wallpapers/1920x1200
    [basename] => autumn_widescreen.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => autumn_widescreen
)

Comment: Then add "." . $dd['extension'] to the filename :D

Comment: but for this link "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRriYVsmTPMn-8zkAKAtTzghAwUeQwaqmZCJTc127h7-WFYIpNS" 
it is not giving me extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just sanitize the filename before trying to create the file. Just create an MD5 string from the pic url.

```
file_put_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/get_img/".md5($pic_name),$rawImage);
```